# Sql Group by and Ordering

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables. 1)Category table, 2)table having Reports belonging to different categories and 3)an event table which keeps track of reports being accessed. I’m writing a stored procedure to rank and  display either top ten or all the  reports Ordered by category, reports belonging to which have gotten the maximum number of hits. Trend is calculated by comparing the hits received by report in the current period to the hits received by previous period.
This is the simplified schema of the tables.

```
ReportCategory Table 
RportCategoryId  CategoryName 

ApplicationReport Table
ApplicationReportId  ReportCategoryId  ReportName

Events Table
EventId ReportId CreatedDate
```

If during the period reports belonging to Inventory gets maximum number of hits and Sales second most then the result should be like

```
Rank  Category  ReportName           Percentage_Change  Trend
1    Inventory  Inventory Turn        42%               Up
     Inventory  Inventory Stock       18%               Up
2    Sales      Discounted Sales      12%               Down
     Sales      Sales return          30%               Up
```

This is what I've come up with

```
SELECT TOP 10 T1.CategoryName AS Category,T1.ReportName, (ABS(100 * (T1.TotalCategoryHits - T2.TotalCategoryHits)) / T2.TotalCategoryHits)+'%' AS PercentageChange,
    CASE When (T1.TotalCategoryHits - T2.TotalCategoryHits) > 0 Then 'Upward'
    WHEN (T1.TotalCategoryHits - T2.TotalCategoryHits) < 0 THEN 'Downward' 
    ELSE 'No Change' END AS Trend
    FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(c.CategoryId) AS TotalCategoryHits,COUNT(r.ReportCategoryId) Total,c.CategoryName,r.ReportName FROM Event e
    inner join Reports r ON r.ReportId = CAST(e.ReportId As INT)
    inner join Category c ON r.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
    WHERE e.CreatedDate >= @CurrentPeriodStartDate AND e.CreatedBy <= @CurrentPeriodEndDate
    GROUP BY c.ReportCategoryName,r.ReportName,e.ReportId) T1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(c.CategoryId) AS TotalCategoryHits,COUNT(r.ReportCategoryId) Total,c.CategoryName,r.ReportName FROM Event e
    inner join Reports r ON r.ReportId = CAST(e.ReportId As INT)
    inner join Category c ON r.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
    where e.CreatedDate >= @PrevPeriodStartDate And e.CreatedDate <= @PrevPeriodEndDate
    GROUP BY c.ReportCategoryName,r.ReportName,e.ReportId) T2 on T1.ReportId = T2.ReportId
    ORDER BY T1.TotalCategoryHits DESC
```

and I'm nowhere near the desired result.
I want the rows to be ordered by the Category which has gotten the maximum number of hits but when I include ReportName in the Group By to make it part of the result I lose the ordering.And I also dont know how to display the rank.

EDIT: [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a950/11)

Names of the columns are different from my description here because I have used the schema of original Database.For some unknown reason my query is not working.May be because I have changed some column names and types.But schema is there.

Comment: Without sample data this is very hard to answer. Please set up a sql fiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com) and please state the version of your SQL Server.

Comment: I'm using Sql Server 2014

Comment: You did not provide sample data... With SQL Server 2014 you can use window functions. Look at aggregate functions like `COUNT` or `RANK` in combination with `OVER`. This should be better than your sub-selects with  `GROUP BY`. If you provide sample data, I'm quite sure, one of the experts here would find a solution quickly...

Comment: Hi just looked through some old stuff and found your edit... Sorry for the late reaction! In future cases please write a comment with the user's name with an `@`-symbol (e.g. `@Shnugo`). There was no notification of your edit. Had to find this activly... And Please tell me, if this is still an open question for you...